# Woocommerce / Wordpress add button to page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce for a wordpress theme, i can figure everything out except one thing

how do i add this button (manual on the website)

http://www.fashiolista.com/content/fashiolista-button/

to a product-page in woocommerce (next to add-to-cart button) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit share.php in the templete of your theme. If your theme doesn't have it then you will have to create it and you can add the custom buttons there.